# How HistorianRecord work ? I want to save history for all transactions based on asset id

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

How HistorianRecord work ? I want to save history for all transactions based on asset id. How can i achieve this in hyperldeger fabric ?

Answer (score 0):

That history is already there. Every time an asset changes, a new transaction is created and it goes on the ledger, meaning that you already have a history of all the changes related to one asset.

You can verify this by playing with composer-playground and you will see the behaviour.

A blockchain system, such as Hyperledger is immutable. This however, doesn't mean that you can't change your assets. What it means is that you cannot change a transaction that has already been committed. This is the biggest thing really.

If you create a rest api using *composer-rest-api*, you will get endpoints for all your assets and you will get an endpoint for the historian side of things. The issue is that the functionality is not yet there, so you can't load all state changes for an asset yet. There is an open ticket for it I believe, but as of yet, this is not yet available.

Answer (score 0):

for programmatic method ("I want to GET history", rather than save), see this Stack Overflow for Asset History -> [Historian for a particular participant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783822/historian-for-a-particular-participant/51820465#51820465) (Asset History) and then for transaction History, you can use something a loopback filter on your transaction REST API endpoint eg. for a `Trade` transaction class, something like:

```
var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/Trade?filter='{%22where%22:{%22asset_id%22:%22resource:org.acme.biznet.Commodity#ABC%22}%2C %22include%22:%22resolve%22}'
    json: true
};

let results = await rp(options);
    //console.log("Return value from REST API is " + results);

results.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.timestamp > b.timestamp) return 1;
  if (a.timestamp < b.timestamp) return -1;
});

console.log(" ");
console.log(" ");
console.log(`TRANSACTION HISTORY for Asset ID:  ${results[0].commodity.tradingSymbol} is: `);
console.log("================================================== ");
console.log(" ");
for (const asset of results) {

      console.log("Type   Transaction Date          Transaction ID                                                     New Ownership     ");
     console.log("=====================================================================================================================");

     console.log(`${asset.$class.split(".").pop()}  ${asset.timestamp}  ${asset.transactionId}   ${asset.newOwner.tradeId}`);
 }
```