# Native API not available in web runtime. Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

To get the complete log of a particular participant. I was following the instruction from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51820465/9790416)

and below is the code. It is throwing an error in Composer Playground as **Native API not available in web runtime**

```
async function participantHistory(tx) {

    const partId = tx.tradeid;
    const nativeSupport = tx.nativeSupport;
    // const partRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.example.trading.Trader')

    const nativeKey = getNativeAPI().createCompositeKey('Asset:org.example.trading.Trader', [partId]);
    const iterator = await getNativeAPI().getHistoryForKey(nativeKey);
    let results = [];
    let res = {done : false};
    while (!res.done) {
        res = await iterator.next();

        if (res && res.value && res.value.value) {
            let val = res.value.value.toString('utf8');
            if (val.length > 0) {
               console.log("@debug val is  " + val );
               results.push(JSON.parse(val));
            }
        }
        if (res && res.done) {
            try {
                iterator.close();
            }
            catch (err) {
            }
        }
    }
    var newArray = [];
    for (const item of results) {
            newArray.push(getSerializer().fromJSON(item));
    }
    console.log("@debug the results to be returned are as follows: ");

    return newArray; // returns something to my NodeJS client (called via REST API)
}
```

It is mentioned in the documentation too [Calling Hyperledger Fabric APIs in transaction processor functions](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts)

Please help how to use this getNativeAPI.

Comment: hi there, the message 'not available in web runtime' really does mean its not available in the browser (ie no underlying Fabric environment) . You need a Fabric environment to use Fabric APIs - see the [docs](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html) - in particular, 'Step Four' - 'Install Hyperledger Fabric' - then install your business network - eg see the [Dev tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial) and create business network card(s) that connect to the Fabric -  then add in your logic per above etc

Comment: thanks Paul, I did as you said, now I am getting another error as "Error: transaction returned with failure: Error: object type or attribute not a non-zero length string"

Comment: hi, not sure of your setup - but it sounds like your transaction isn't returning any results and that requires sufficient data  :-) you can always write debug msgs to your chaincode container and see what is actually returned (eg `results` ?)  - a simpler example is posted here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts#read-only-transaction-processor-functions-(query-processor-functions)  (search for `getHistoryforKey` )